# How to migrate from d3 v3 to d3 v4?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Weird error here. I am not sure what the deal is. I am getting this error: `Uncaught TypeError: t.eachBefore is not a function` when using d3 v4.

More specifically, for this line:

```
let treeData = tree(root);
```

Where the tree function is nothing more than:

```
let tree = d3.tree()
.size([width, height])
.separation(function (a, b) {
    return ((a.parent == root) && (b.parent == root)) ? 3 : 1;
});
```

I am using the correct version of d3 (v4). It is saved locally using this source: https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js

In my HTML, I am referencing the locally saved copy:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="d3.min.js"></script>
```

Both `tree and root` have reliable data and are defined so I am not really sure. I have looked through documentation and couldn't find this pinpoint error.

Has anyone experienced this?

Comment: use the non-min version and you get a better line number of the error

Comment: That says that root.eachBefore is not a function.

Comment: what is root at that line: use console.log or debugger

Comment: The problem is in your data.  You should add that to the question so others can help  you.

Comment: The differences between D3 v3 and v4 can be found here: https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#changes-in-d3-40 but if you can, use the latest version (v5.7.0).

Comment: This is still a problem. Has anybody found a fix?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the hierarchical data must be "parsed" in a way that d3 understands it.
Considering the following example dataset:

```
{
  "name": "Eve",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "Cain"
    },
    {
      "name": "Seth",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Enos"
        },
        {
          "name": "Noam"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Abel"
    },
    {
      "name": "Awan",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Enoch"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Azura"
    }
  ]
}
```

The tree structure can be created as follows, whereas the second line (`d3.hierarchy(...)`) handles the important "parsing":

```
var treeStructure = d3.tree().size([width, height]);
root = d3.hierarchy(root, (d) => d.children)
var nodesData = treeStructure(root);
var links = nodesData.links(nodes);
```